# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException length=42; index=42 android.text.Layout$HorizontalMeasurementProvider.get(Layout.java:1416)

Tags: arrayindexoutofboundsexception

It feels like a bug in the system. How to solve this problem

```
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2600)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2600)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2600)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2600)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2600)
com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:448)
com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1829)
android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3307)
androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(SourceFile:69)
com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:410)
android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12016)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4809)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4623)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4161)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4214)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4180)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4307)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4188)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4364)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4161)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4214)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4180)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4188)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4161)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6682)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6656)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6617)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6785)
android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:187)
android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6501)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

It looks like a bug in the system. I don't know why. I can't find the corresponding solution. Some of them have encountered phase problems

Comment: It's not a bug in the system. An array with a length of 42 has valid indexes of 0 to 41, so an index of 42 exceeds the array bounds. This is basic Java.

Comment: This does not specifically tell me which line of code is wrong. This means that there is a problem in textview. How can I fix it

Comment: @zhej Facing a similar issue. Were you able to find a solution?